# MongoDB setup: mongo.log permissions wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, osx-mountain-lion

First time Mongo user here running OSX Mountain Lion.

Installed MongoDB via homebrew. Upon typing mongod I get the following message:

```
$ mongod
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
can't open [/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log] for log file: errno:13 Permission denied
```

What is the correct command to apply permissions to my mongodb folder? I am the admin user on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

`chmod u+w /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

Gives the current user (the logged in user running mongo) write permissions to the log.